# Read Source of an html file in vb.net widows forms

Tags: html, vb.net

I am developing a windows application in vb.net. In my application I have to read the source of a `.html` file which is stored in my local directory.

How can I do that?

Comment: Write all code yourself using like FileStream.Read [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) or use full component  PM> Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: can you provide some sample code? I am not understanding this. @Abdullah

Comment: `Dim htmlSource As String = File.ReadAllText(path)`